# How to import external module in python macro for OpenOffice?

Tags: python, macros, import, openoffice.org, openoffice-writer

I'm writing a macro for OpenOffice in python, and I have a problem. I want to import external module (gdata) so i write

```
import uno
import gdata.calendar.service
```

but when I try execute macro (Tools -> Marcos -> Run Macro..) I always get `ImportError` :/
I have `gdata` module in my `PYTHONPATH`, it's working when I test it in interpreter.

What can I do to import module which is not part of Open Office UNO?